# Are there default icons for use in a QTreeWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtreewidget, qicon

I have a QTreeWidget and I want to add icons, are there a default set to pick from such as the file folder in explorer and a blank piece of paper icon?

Answer (score 6):

There are several icons by default, for example:

With [`QStyle::standardIcon(...)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#standardIcon):

```
QIcon dir_icon = QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_DirIcon);
QIcon file_icon = QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_FileIcon);
```

with [`QFileIconProvider::icon(...)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileiconprovider.html#icon)

```
QFileIconProvider provider;
QIcon dir_icon = provider.icon(QFileIconProvider::Folder);
QIcon file_icon = provider.icon(QFileIconProvider::File);
```

If your OS uses freedesktop then you can use [`QIcon::fromTheme(...)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#fromTheme):

```
QIcon dir_icon = QIcon::fromTheme("folder");
QIcon file_icon = QIcon::fromTheme("text-x-generic")
```

Comment: That worked perfect thanks, but strangely

 QIcon dir_open_icon = QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_DirOpenIcon);

just gave the normal closed dir icon.